# Remove empty space from block when width reduced

Tags: html, css

How to remove this empty space when block reducing width?
It can be flex, doesn't matter.

Here is [CodePan](https://codepen.io/Spawnes/pen/gOjbjZw)

[Initial block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O0So.png)

[When block became smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nbmx.png)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="someStuff">someStuff</div>
  <div class="inputs">
    <div class="block">
      <span>Задать шаг: </span>
      <div class="select-container">
        <select>
          <option value="50">50</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <span>Цветовая схема: </span>
      <div class="select-container">
        <select>
          <option value="YlOrRd">YlOrRd</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the CSS associated with your HTML code ?

Comment: I've add codepan with html and scss.